# SELECT SQL - Join com campos criados

Tags: sql, select

Preciso fazer um join com o produto de dois `SELECT`s diferentes porém, não estou conseguindo chegar a um entendimento.

Preciso que as colunas criadas (`notificacao`) em abas as tabelas sejam comparadas e me retorne os dados da completos da batela painel, mesmo que não identificados na tabela `robo`.

**Tabela: robo**

```
SELECT REPLACE(id_notificacao,'RIxRE-',"") AS 'notificacao',data_input AS 'data_escrita'
FROM robo
WHERE id_notificacao LIKE 'RIxRE%' AND MONTH(data_input) >4*
```

**Tabela: painel**

```
SELECT CONCAT(id_notificacao,'-',ci_sigla) AS 'notificacao',dt_confirmada AS 'data_tratamento'
FROM painel
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta assim

```
Select *
From painel
Left join robo on robo.id_notificacao = painel.id_notificacao
WHERE id_notificacao LIKE 'RIxRE%' AND MONTH(data_input) >4*
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!